# skip NA's when computing dot product

Tags: r

I am adjusting the measurements in a data matrix by subtracting their projections onto the first 1-2 principal components. The problem is, if there is even a single `NA` in the data matrix (almost inevitable for thousands of measurements), the inner product operation `x%*%y` (I also tried `sum(x*y)`, for vectors `x,y`) returns `NA`. Is there a simple way (i.e. avoiding conditional statements and loops) of computing the inner product on the non-NA values, so that the operation actually returns something?

Incidentally, I would like to avoid just replacing `NA`'s with `0`'s, since then I would have to renormalize the vectors at each stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
sum(x*y, na.rm = TRUE)
```